# Why don't my dogs recognize me?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

It's been 4 days since I played and now my dogs don't recognize me and I don't want to kill them.  What can I do so that they recognize me again?

Comment: What do you mean "don't recognise you"? Have they stopped being tame? Stopped sitting/standing? Stopped following you?

Comment: I can't make them sit or stand anymore but they still got their collars

Comment: Are you sure you're logged into the same account? (You're still logging into minecraft and not using an offline account?)

Comment: We can't log in to our account anymore so I'm on a offline

Comment: But my friend is also on offline but her dogs recognize her, how come?

Comment: Have you tried relogging?

Answer (score -1):

If you try to have them stand or sit and if they won't do it, it's because you attacked a monster by them. It hit you once or twice, they tried to help but they were sitting down and you killed it. They won't sit or stand. It's happened to me before, but I'm sorry but I don't know what to do. Also, try feeding them.